# Showing that $A(\overline{B_1^X}) \subseteq Y$ is closed when $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, reflexive-space

**Exercise :**

> Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $X$ be reflexive, $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. If $\overline{B_1^X} = \{ u \in X : \|u\|_X \leq 1\}$,  show that $A(\overline{B_1^X}) \subseteq Y$ is closed.

**Intuition :**

The closed unit ball $\overline{B_1^X}$ is closed, convex and bounded in $X$.  Let $b_n \in \overline{B_1^X}$ and $Ab_n \xrightarrow{w} y \in Y$. Since $X$ is reflexive, then $\overline{B_1^X}$ is weakly compact and of course $b_n$ lies in a weakly compact set. Hence we have a subsequence $b'_n \xrightarrow{w} x \in X$. But since $\overline{B_1^X}$ is also weakly closed, it would be $x \in \overline{B_1^X}$. Now, it is $A \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y) \Leftrightarrow A \in \mathcal{L}(X_w,Y_w)$. Hence $Ab'_n \xrightarrow{w} Ax$ which must coincide with $y$ as we showed a weak convergence earlier, thus $y = Ax \in \overline{B_1^X}$ and the desired closedness is proven.

**Question (1) :** Is my approach correct and rigorous enough ?

**Question (2):** I feel like this is a bit too much working around with all the sequences. I know sometimes that with some statement-theorems one may tackle it faster. Any alternatives would be much appreciated !

Comment: "rigorous enough?" This is subjective, in the end.

Comment: @SK19 Sure. But at least, is it correct ?

Comment: It is correct. I would be inclined to write $A b_n \stackrel{w}{\to}y$ to emphasise the convergence type.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the heads up !

Comment: You can avoid sequences: $X$ is reflexive, so $\overline{B_1}$ is weakly compact. Since $A$ is weak-weak continuous $A(\overline{B_1})$ is weakly compact, thus weakly closed, thus norm closed.